# Evento onclick Jquery no toma (JS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, eventos, onclick

Hola estoy haciendo un evento llamado onclick de js lo que sucede que al presionar el botón no me manda las alertas de "Confirm"

El código es el siguiente.

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#DANGERDANGERDANGER").click(function() {
        if (confirm("¿Cancelar atencion?")) {
            if (confirm("¿Seguro?")) {
                if (confirm("¿De veritas?")) {
                    if (confirm("Ok, confio en ti")) {
                        if (confirm("Ultima oportunidad para arrepentirse...")) {
                             ...
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
    });
    </script>
```

Y donde lo estoy llamando es con el siguente boton

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="DANGERDANGERDANGER" onclick="DANGERDANGERDANGER();">
    Boton
</button>
```

El j query lo llamo y está por debajo es decir en el footer. Si se preguntan de porque no está la integrity es porque tengo kamsperky y por motivos de seguridad tenía problemas.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Perdón por no especificar, pero el error que me manda es el siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No está demás decir que [se desaconseja el uso de los eventos inline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these) :) De hecho, ese "onclick" es innecesario, pues ya definiste qué hacer con ese evento en jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error que te muestra es porque estas intentando llamar una funcion que no existe

La forma de hacerlo con javascript es de la siguiente forma:

```js
    //Ahora es una funcion y la puedes llamar desde el boton conn un evento onclick
    //Incluso no necesitarias Jquery para lograr esto
    function DANGERDANGERDANGER(){
        if (confirm("¿Cancelar atencion?")) {
            if (confirm("¿Seguro?")) {
                if (confirm("¿De veritas?")) {
                    if (confirm("Ok, confio en ti")) {
                        
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

```html
<button type="button" id="Mybutton" onclick="DANGERDANGERDANGER()">
        Boton
    </button>
```

Te explico porque: cuando creas el boton ya le estas dando el evento onclick para que llame la funcion `DANGERDANGERDANGER`, y tu lo que estas haciendo con **jquery** es de nuevo tomar el boton y darle otro evento `onclick` para ejecute una funcion anonima

De la otra forma con jquery es:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="DANGERDANGERDANGER" >
        Boton
    </button>


 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#DANGERDANGERDANGER").click(function() {
        if (confirm("¿Cancelar atencion?")) {
            if (confirm("¿Seguro?")) {
                if (confirm("¿De veritas?")) {
                    if (confirm("Ok, confio en ti")) {
                        if (confirm("Ultima oportunidad para arrepentirse...")) {
                             ...
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
    });
    </script>
```

Aca lo que haces es crear el boton sin ningin evento, pero en la funcion `onready` de Jquery obtienes el boton por su `id` y le seteas el evento para ejecute una funcion anonima, tambien de esta forma es valido pero debes seleccionar una

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta tan completa, ya entendí cómo funciona como y porque tambien a los demas que me respondieron que me resolvieron dudas al como llamarlo con o sin